# Why does true == 'true' statement in JS return false?

Tags: javascript

Question is in the title. I've just tried to run next statements in Chrome console and got strange (as for me) result:

```
true == 'true' // returns false
'true' == true // returns false
```

Why does it go such way? Why doesn't typecast work there, but in the next statement works?

```
if ('true') true // returns true
```

Comment: @Hogan: It'll still be `false`.

Comment: http://docs.nodejitsu.com/articles/javascript-conventions/what-are-truthy-and-falsy-values

Comment: Typecasting works for the first two snippets too, though `true` is casted to `1` which !== `'true'`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Because they don't represent equally convertible types/values. The conversion used by `==` is much more complex than a simple `toBoolean` conversion used by `if ('true')`.

So given this code `true == 'true'`, it finds this:

> *"If `Type(x)` is `Boolean`, return the result of the comparison `ToNumber(x) == y`."*

So you see it starts by becoming `ToNumber(true) == 'true'`, which is `1 == 'true'`, and then tries again, where it now finds:

> *If `Type(x)` is `Number` and `Type(y)` is `String`, return the result of the comparison `x == ToNumber(y)`.*

So now it's doing `1 == ToNumber('true')`, which is `1 == NaN`, which of course is `false`.

Comment: +1 well explained! could you link the sources of that information?

Comment: @PhilippSander: Use Rocket's link. It's an unofficial copy, but has nice cross links and annotations. It's the *Abstract Equality Comparison Algorithm*.

Answer (score 2):

The `==` operator uses ECMAScript's [abstract equality algorithm](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.3) which is quite complex. Its exact behavior depends on the types of each argument involved, and each step usually involves another invoking another ECMAScript function.

The `if(condition)` statement converts `condition` to a boolean using ECMAScript's [`ToBoolean`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.2) which is simple enough to be expressed in a single table. As you can see in the spec, any string is truthy (according to `ToBoolean`) if it has a nonzero length.

Answer (score 0):

true = boolean type

'true' = string type

the expression "if ('true')" evaluates the 'true'(string) as true(boolean) on the same way that if('foo') or any other string does.

Answer (score 0):

A non-empty string will return true:

- `if ('0') true;  // true`
- `if ('false') true; // true`
- `if ('anything') true; // true`

A null string will return undefined and thus is *falsy*:

- `if ('') true;  // not true`

When comparing types, JavaScript will try to do some magic for you:

- `if (1 == "1") true; // true`

But it fails when converting a string to boolean:

- `if(true == "true") true; // not true`

Answer (score -3):

true is a boolean value
'true' is a string.

you are comparing different data types.  [look here: http://w3schools.com/js/js_datatypes.asp](http://w3schools.com/js/js_datatypes.asp)

Comment: javascript converts the types when using == but not with ===

Comment: oh please.  lots of hate.  But w3 really helped me back in the day to get going with javascript.  They never tried to be "the spec".  Just a straightforward way to get people going.  In any school, you always oversimplify things for the sake of comprehension, then you present the "truth" later.

Comment: @AwokeKnowing maybe but what do you think SO users expect? I can bet not "truth" in your meaning. MDN 100500 times better for referencing. At last they have own browser and JS engine and w3fools not.

Comment: @antyrat: there was a time where w3fools had a point, but their biggest argument now is that w3schools isn't wikified and so isn't updated at supersonic speeds :) They do have a forum and suggestion methods, which they didn't before.  Instead of asking them to wikify, another site should provide that option.... oh wait, others have tried and have been eclipsed by w3schools, which is often 95% accurate and you can google the other 5% or come to SO if you need help.